# Is there a way to write these angular bindings more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form embedded in a view in my Angular JS 1.2.6 application.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as signin">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <form name="signin.myForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': (signin.myForm.name.$error.required || signin.myForm.name.$error.minlength) && signin.myForm.name.$dirty}">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="signin.myForm.data.name" required ng-minlength="3">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="signin.myForm.name.$error.required && signin.myForm.name.$dirty" >Name is required.</span>
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="signin.myForm.name.$error.minlength && signin.myForm.name.$dirty" >Must be at least 3 characters.</span>
    </div>      
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!signin.myForm.$valid" ng-click="signin.submit()">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

with the controller being:

```
 app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$log',function($log){
 var ctrl = this;

 ctrl.submit = function(){
 console.log(ctrl.myForm);

 if(ctrl.myForm.$valid){
   console.log('the form is valid');
   }
  };
}]);
```

As you can see, to get the form field's data to be part of the same scope as the signin I was taught to first do `ng-controller="LoginCtrl as signin"` and then I wind up with convoluted names for models and properties like `signin.myForm.name.$error.required`

Is this the correct way to do it?  It seems to work, but although I am a noob this seems like a bit tangled to me.  Is this really the best practice?

Comment: You can update to 1.3 and use [`ngMessages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) ;).

Comment: I wish. Still need to support IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more common to see something like this, where you attach things to an injected `$scope` instead of `this`, and then you don't have to put a namespace qualifier on the references in the HTML.

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': (myForm.name.$error.required || myForm.name.$error.minlength) && myForm.name.$dirty}">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="signin.myForm.data.name" required ng-minlength="3">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="signin.myForm.name.$error.required && myForm.name.$dirty" >Name is required.</span>
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.minlength && myForm.name.$dirty" >Must be at least 3 characters.</span>
    </div>      
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="submit()">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$log',function($scope, $log){

        $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log($scope.myForm);

        if($scope.myForm.$valid){
           console.log('the form is valid');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: That helps, for sure. Another developer here had told me it's newer, better practice to do the namespacing.  Is that just a stylistic thing, or is there something to this?

Comment: Look at the guides in the angular docs.  You won't find anything about using the namespace aliases: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

Even in their example of nested scopes (which would be the only time I could see namespacing as potentially helpful), they don't use namespacing.  I think as you learn more about `$scope` concept, it's just as simple (in the sense of [simple vs. familiar](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy)) to just rely on the injected `$scope`.  I'd love for someone to give it a good reason, though, I love learning new things.